# How to use Python Requests to submit a form with invisible reCAPTCHA?

Tags: python, forms, python-requests, invisible-recaptcha, grecaptcha

I want to send anonymous emails using Python. I use an online anonymous email sending tool called [emkei.cz](https://emkei.cz/). I want to use this same tool programmatically.

How to fill out that form on the website (emkei.cz) and submit it to send an anonymous email using `python-requests`?

I do not want to use anything like `selenium` or `mechanize` because they are slow (even when I run `selenium` headlessly) and are not required for a basic HTML form which I can simulate through requests.

## What I have tried

I filled out the form and checked the requests made when submitting the form in the network tab of Microsoft Edge developer tools.
I tried to simulate those requests using `requests` library in Python.

The mail was sent successfully. I noted down the headers and payload  (data) as well.
I wrote a simple Python script with the same form values, trying to send a mail.
However, it didn't work.

To debug, I checked `r.text`. It was returning the same input form I just filled instead of the success message saying 'Email sent successfully'.

[Here](https://replit.com/@nixdonut/PeskyDirtyObject#main.py) is the code I am using:

```py
import requests


def send_email(to, subject, body, debug):
    headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Length": "3072",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryIGzbcUtI3oNRwVLD",
        "Cookie": "__gads=ID=a33e3b44296022c7-22066d337bd100ce:T=1648910614:RT=1648910614:S=ALNI_MZLGzNvZhCPKcpiV2aS8Nkg4um4SQ",
        "Host": "emkei.cz",
        "Origin": "null",
        "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="99"',
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Windows"',
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.74 Safari/537.36 Edg/99.0.1150.55"
    }

    payload = {
        "fromname": "LifeAsAnRPG Team",
        "from": "team@lifeasanrpg.com",
        "rcpt": to,
        "subject": subject,
        "attachment": "(binary)",
        "reply": "",
        "errors": "",
        "cc": "",
        "bcc": "",
        "importance": "normal",
        "xmailer": "0",
        "customxm": "",
        "confirmd": "",
        "confirmr": "",
        "addh": "",
        "smtp": "",
        "smtpp": "",
        "current": "on",
        "charset": "utf-8",
        "mycharset": "",
        "encrypt": "no",
        "ctype": "plain",
        "rte": "0",
        "text": body,
        "g-recaptcha-response": "03AGdBq24yOL4Cas-N8rzxpVSHZnJR0Ec7V_8tylGd_6IpLZotF1hqQZo2Ukyt9qw3CWAqDV7onb2TeJ25cTx9fWPf9icUaK8QCE3HGoxFMO9wYvXB5RNDSkQGbpuU_7mRZl_RDs3RVx6Savi0-PENoz1fvfUBmcKhPbPDXnRWyfayDjS1DrTU0hTivr2Xkp4W3KxBpPBg0lp7W_hgujMxqa5fjXz46Do9ZUq3G2DCRciuwBLYXS3v9nSEW1wqhFtdWfRbby50iougT0DGAWzN5vbs6o0X7YzTit6uyNO2zF0-ZECTH6YNpTMgdlC4t4QquS0-BhXPBOdDCICccYafyGoQgioaPcQt--NfaPFSYvLnVhCjFJ2y2Kl7sFFviGn-lgnvK65NpSKlNjYrSHB29LsLcF1zghmwjPZtWJ7q7rljAhz7rH9Iyxs",
        "ok": "Send"
    }

    request = requests.request(
        method="POST",
        url="https://emkei.cz/",
        headers=headers,
        data=payload
    )

    if debug:
        print(request.text)
        print(request.status_code)

    if request.status_code != 200:
        return -1

    return 0


send_email(
    to="test-test@mailinator.com",
    subject="Test subject.",
    body="""
        Test line one.
        Test line two.
        """,
    debug=True
)
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the captcha and `g-recaptcha-response` payload. I was not asked for any captcha when filling the form though.

Please try visiting the website ([Emkei's Anonymous Mailer](https://emkei.cz/), linked above as well) and tell me how to send an email programmatically through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is invisible reCAPTCHA, so you need to render the page to get `g-recaptcha-response`.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions#recaptcha_v2_invisible_recaptcha_badge

You can use `requests-html`, which will automatically download Chromium on the first render.
https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/

1. Render the page and set the captcha in `send_email` function, before the POST request:

   ```py
   from requests_html import HTMLSession
   session = HTMLSession()
   response = session.get("https://emkei.cz/")
   # response.html.render()
   for _ in range(10):
       if response.html.search('name="g-recaptcha-response" value="{}"') is None:
           response.html.render()
   payload['g-recaptcha-response'] = response.html.search('name="g-recaptcha-response" value="{}"')[0]
   ```
2. Comment out the `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=...` header:

   ```py
   # "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=...
   ```

   You shouldn't specify your own boundary, since the multipart data is built by `requests`.
   https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1997
3. Add the following failure check(s) alongside `request.status_code != 200`:

   ```py
   # if "The invisible reCAPTCHA test wasn't successful. Please, try again." in request.text:
   #     return -1
   if "E-mail sent successfully" not in request.text:
       return -1
   ```

---

On Windows, you may encounter issues with `requests-html` trying to download Chromium.
https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/325

## Invisible reCAPTCHA may still block requests

Initially, a single `response.html.render()` worked perfectly.

After running *xx* times within 1 hour, I needed `for _ in range(10)` and I occasionally get `TimeoutError` during `render()`:

> pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 8000 ms exceeded.

After running *xxx* times within 1 hour, https://emkei.cz/ mostly returns `"The invisible reCAPTCHA test wasn't successful. Please, try again."`.

Comment: Thank you! This was a very comprehensive answer giving me exactly the information I needed. How do I award the bounty?

Comment: Never mind, I awarded it!